# How can I move xticks and xticklabels up?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I've got this code that is supposed to make a heatmap, but with circles instead of squares/rectangles, so far testing it with placeholder colors, looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from typing import List, T
from random import uniform
def l_flatten(l: List[T]) -> List[T]:
    return [j for i in l for j in i]
def get_luminance(color: str) -> float:
    # taken from Seaborn's utils
    rgb = mcl.colorConverter.to_rgba_array(color)[:, :3]
    rgb = np.where(rgb <= .03928, rgb / 12.92, ((rgb + .055) / 1.055) ** 2.4)
    lum = rgb.dot([.2126, .7152, .0722])
    try:
        lum = lum.item()
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return lum
class CircleHeatmap:
    def __init__(self,
                 ax: plt.Axes,
                 df: pd.DataFrame,
                 colors: List[str],
                 annot_show: bool,
                 annot_size: float,
                 circle_size: float,
                 x_labels: List[str],
                 x_labels_size: float,
                 x_labels_color: str,
                 y_labels: List[str],
                 y_labels_size: float,
                 y_labels_color: str) -> None:
        # pass user-provided variables
        self.ax = ax
        self.df = df
        self.colors = colors
        self.annot_show = annot_show
        self.annot_size = annot_size
        self.circle_size = circle_size
        self.x_labels = x_labels
        self.x_labels_size = x_labels_size
        self.x_labels_color = x_labels_color
        self.y_labels = y_labels
        self.y_labels_size = y_labels_size
        self.y_labels_color = y_labels_color
        # pass technical variables
        self.y_size, self.x_size = self.df.shape
        self.x_arr, self.y_arr = np.meshgrid(np.arange(self.x_size),
                                             np.arange(self.y_size))
        self.x_arr, self.y_arr = ((self.x_arr + 0.5).flat,
                                  (self.y_arr + 0.5).flat)
        self.x_len, self.y_len = [np.linspace(0, len(i), len(i) + 1)[:-1] + 0.5
                                  for i in (self.x_labels, self.y_labels)]
        self.df_values = l_flatten(self.df.values.tolist())
    def plot(self) -> None:
        self.ax.scatter(self.x_arr, self.y_arr,
                        s = self.circle_size ** 2,
                        c = self.colors)
    def labels(self) -> None:
        self.ax.set_xticks(self.x_len)
        self.ax.set_yticks(self.y_len)
        self.ax.set_xticklabels(self.x_labels, fontsize = self.x_labels_size,
                           color = self.x_labels_color)
        self.ax.set_yticklabels(self.y_labels, fontsize = self.y_labels_size,
                           color = self.y_labels_color)
def main() -> None:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20, 30))
    df = pd.DataFrame([[uniform(0, 1) for j in range(20)] for i in range(30)])
    colors = ["#EC4E20", "#FF9505", "#016FB9"] * 200
    heatmap = CircleHeatmap(ax = ax,
                            df = df,
                            colors = colors,
                            annot_show = False,
                            annot_size = 16,
                            circle_size = 45,
                            x_labels = [i for i in range(20)],
                            x_labels_size = 20,
                            x_labels_color = "black",
                            y_labels = [i for i in range(30)],
                            y_labels_size = 20,
                            y_labels_color = "black")
    heatmap.plot()
    heatmap.labels()
    for i in ["top", "bottom", "right", "left"]:
        ax.spines[i].set_visible(False)
    plt.savefig("test2.png")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As a result, I get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA8XQ.jpg). My question is: how can I move the ticks and the labels on the x-axis up a little bit, preferrably with an option to control them with a variable?

Comment: Try this: `ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0));ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0))`

Comment: Worked, but made the text tiny, looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/MctIDsY) now. Doubling x_labels_size and y_labels_size (both set to 40 now) in the call to CircleHeatmap literally changes nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar result, but only commented on the settings since you were so familiar with them. Once again, a fix was needed and I will respond with the corrected code. I don't know if I was able to add the code in the best place. The following code can help.

```
def labels(self) -> None:
    self.ax.set_xticks(self.x_len)
    self.ax.set_yticks(self.y_len)
    self.ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0))
    self.ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0))
    self.ax.set_xticklabels(self.x_labels, fontsize = self.x_labels_size,
                       color = self.x_labels_color)
    self.ax.set_yticklabels(self.y_labels, fontsize = self.y_labels_size,
                       color = self.y_labels_color)
```

[image]

Comment: That's excellent, thanks!